# Retrieve multiple values from jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I retrieve `petKeys` and `employeeKey` values by using below mentioned jQuery functions ?

```
var whenSelectDateFromCalendar = function () {
    initKeyValues();
    petKeys = ? employeeKey = ?
};


var initKeyValues = function () {
    var petKeys = $('#pets input:checked').map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get().join('+');
    var employeeKey = $('#employee input:checked').map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get().join('+');
}
```

Comment: You must change the initKeyValues function.

Comment: @dystroy can you tell me How ?

Comment: Just send your local `petKeys` and `employeeKey` (that you noted with `?`) over as a parameters to the `initKeyValues` function to fill their values for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return both values in an object. Try this:

```
var whenSelectDateFromCalendar = function () {
    var keys = initKeyValues();

    // use the object returned above to set the vars here
    petKeys = keys.petKeys;
    employeeKey = keys.employeeKey;
};


var initKeyValues = function () {
    var petKeys = $('#pets input:checked').map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get().join('+');
    var employeeKey = $('#employee input:checked').map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get().join('+');

    // return the object containing both values
    return { 
        employeeKey: employeeKey,
        petKeys: petKeys
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1 - Return multiple results within an object

```
var initKeyValues = function () {
    var petKeys = $('#pets input:checked').map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get().join('+');

    var employeeKey = $('#employee input:checked').map(function () { return $(this).val(); }).get().join('+');}

    return {"petKeys": petKeys,  "employeeKey": employeeKey}
};

var whenSelectDateFromCalendar = function () {
    var result = initKeyValues();

    petKeys = result.petKeys;
    employeeKey = result.employeeKey;   

    // or even...

    petKeys = result["petKeys"];
    employeeKey = result["employeeKey"];
};
```

### Option 2: Return multiple results within an array

```
var initKeyValues = function () {
    var petKeys = $('#pets input:checked').map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get().join('+');

    var employeeKey = $('#employee input:checked').map(function () { return $(this).val(); }).get().join('+');}

    return [petKeys, employeeKey];
};

var whenSelectDateFromCalendar = function () {
    var result = initKeyValues();

    petKeys = result[0];
    employeeKey = result[1];
};
```